# Kendo UI Grid custom validation message

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-validator

[Here is an example of working custom validation, but without an error message.](http://dojo.telerik.com/IToLo) To test it, set the value of "Lowest" to something higher to or equal to the row's "Highest" value.

The functionality I need is already working, I just can't figure out how to set a custom error message for my custom validator in a Kendo UI Grid.

Every example I find either has no custom message *or* uses a construct like the following, which *does not work*, at least not anymore from what I can tell:

```
{
  validation: {
    rules: {
      myCustomValidator: ...
    },
    messages: {
      myCustomValidator: 'My custom error message'
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the validation message as the value of the attribute "data-lowerThanHighest-msg" of the input text. You can do it like that: `input.attr("data-lowerThanHighest-msg", "Lowest must be lower than Highest");`

See your demo revised [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/IToLo/2)